# lose some items by using Flux.push() in Reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

My code is as follows:

```
public class SequenceCreator {

    public Consumer<List<Integer>> consumer;

    public Flux<Integer> createNumberSequence() {
        return Flux.push(sink -> consumer = items -> items.forEach(sink::next));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SequenceCreator sequenceCreator = new SequenceCreator();

        List<Integer> sequence1 = Lists.newArrayList(1,2,3,4,5);
        List<Integer> sequence2 = Lists.newArrayList(6,7,8,9,10);

        Thread producingThread1 = new Thread(
                () -> sequenceCreator.consumer.accept(sequence1));

        Thread producingThread2 = new Thread(
                () -> sequenceCreator.consumer.accept(sequence2));

        sequenceCreator.createNumberSequence().subscribe(System.out::println);

        producingThread1.start();
        producingThread2.start();

        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

1
2
3
4
5
7
8
9
10

I don't know why the number 6 is not output？Is it the cause of multi-thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why the number 6 is not output？Is it the cause of multi-thread?

Yes, almost certainly. Have a look at the Javadoc for [`Flux.push`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#push-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> Programmatically create a Flux with the capability of emitting multiple elements from a **single-threaded producer** through the FluxSink API. For a multi-threaded capable alternative, see **create(Consumer).**

You're not using a single-threaded producer (violating the documented requirement), so the behaviour is essentially undefined in this scenario. You need to switch to `Flux.create` as the doc suggests, since you're using multiple threads to publish.

Comment: I read from multiple answers on stackoverflow that escaping the sink from the lambda is not recommended (for example stackoverflow.com/a/56063933 and its comments) and that you must use processors instead. Do you have info on this ? thanks